# Send email from Contact form directly without opening gmail application

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

I want to send email directly to admin email without opening gmail application through URL package in flutter URL package work perfectly but that is not required. I want to do it through fire-base where I also want to save all data send to admin email. I need to know the email function of firebase or any such function that help me to send direct email.

```
_launchURL(String toMailId, String subject, String body) async {
  var url = 'mailto:$toMailId?subject=$subject&body=$body';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

Comment: use - https://pub.dev/packages/mailer

Comment: ok thanks I will try